# С чего начать изучение С++

Tags: книги

Какие тектовые редакторы компиляторы необходимы? Желательно на русском. Вообщем, в программирование я не особо понимаю, поэтому убедительная просьба писать простым и понятным языком. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Начните с учебника русского языка

Comment: Я вполне серьезно.

Comment: Таких вопросов задано огромное множество! И на большую их часть грамотно отвечено! Поэтому попытайтесь сначала найти ответ самостоятельно, а уж потом задавайте вопрос! + почитайте [справку](http://hashcode.ru/faq/) для начала!

Comment: афтар патрудился бы каканить редактнуть своя вопрос чтоба нанрмольна читулася

Answer (score 3):

Скачивайте `MS VisualStudio 2010` , устанавливайте. Потом в поисковике пишете `"HELLO WORD C++"` и смотрите примеры, и пробуете повторить у себя. И вот когда что-то будет не получаться пишете подробно проблему на этот форум и получаешь ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Я в детстве начинал с книги Дэвис Чепмен "Изучи MSVC++.NET за 21 день". И Павловская/Щупак. А вообще, в Инете есть куча книг, в т.ч. для чайников, рекомендую.

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом прочитайте что такое компилятор. После этого скачайте и установите любой компилятор который придет вам по душе, лично я пользуюсь Visual Studio 2012 Professional.
После этого скачайте книгу Лафоре ООП С++, я начинал с неё и скажу что это довольно таки хорошая книга, всё разжевано, много примеров, с подробными объяснениями, комментариями чуть ли не на каждой строчке, книга не занудная, читается легко и интересно, самое главное выполняйте все примеры. И по каждой строчке смотрите и думайте что же на ней выполнится. А после того как прочитаете, вы сами поймете где у вас недочеты :).
Причем книга не новая и там есть множество ошибок (из за плохого перевода) и это послужит хорошей тренировкой.